# How to unassemble x64 reset vector?

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, windbg

I would like to see the first few instructions that my machine executes at startup. On x64 the reset vector is at physical address FFFFFFF0. I have enabled local kernel debugging on my Windows 10, restarted the PC and started WinDbg as Administrator. When doing a kernel debug (File -> Kernel Debug...), I am not sure what to type at the lkd> prompt to unassemble the code. I can do "!db FFFFFFF0" which displays some bytes:

```
 #fffffff0 90 90 e9 83 e8 00 00 00-fc 00 00 00 00 00 e1 ff ................
 #100000000 bb 00 fc 6a 00 00 e1 a9-00 00 bb 00 fc 6a 00 00 ...j.........j..
 #100000010 01 aa 00 00 bb 00 fc 6a-00 00 21 aa 00 00 bb 00 .......j..!.....
 #100000020 fc 6a 00 00 41 aa 00 00-bb 00 fc 6a 00 00 61 aa .j..A......j..a.
 #100000030 00 00 bb 00 fc 6a 00 00-81 aa 00 00 bb 00 fc 6a .....j.........j
 #100000040 00 00 a1 aa 00 00 bb 00-fc 6a 00 00 c1 aa 00 00 .........j......
 #100000050 bb 00 fc 6a 00 00 e1 aa-00 00 bb 00 fc 6a 00 00 ...j.........j..
 #100000060 01 ab 00 00 bb 00 fc 6a-00 00 21 ab 00 00 bb 00 .......j..!.....
```

then I tried "!u FFFFFFF0" which returns:

```
    Op: 
    Dest: 
    Dest: 0
    Src: 
    Srct: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

it is just two nops and a jump if you mean you need to disassemble it as 16 bit

use ur

i patched the first 16 bytes from your query and disassemble it as 16 bit for demo  below

```
0:000> db . l10
772805a6  90 90 e9 83 e8 00 00 00-fc 00 00 00 00 00 e1 ff  ................
0:000> ur . l3
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
772805a6 90              nop
772805a7 90              nop
772805a8 e983e8          jmp     EE2E
0:000>
```

Local Kernel Debugging is not Live it is Dead Debugging it operates on a snap shot
livekd operates on a state as the system  was when dumped

!u is undocumented iirc and doesn't disassemble it provides a verbose details of a single instruction

```
0:000> u .+1 l1
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2d:
772805a7 8975fc          mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],esi
0:000> !u 772805a7
        Op: mov
        Dest: esi
        Dest: fffffffe
        Src: dword ptr [ebp-4]
        Srct: 0
0:000>
```

if you are looking for disassembling something like bios code use up
unassemble physical

```
 kd> up cs:7c00 l1
0008:00007c00 eb52            jmp     00007c54
kd> up cs:7c54 l20
0008:00007c54 fa              cli
0008:00007c55 33c0            xor     eax,eax
0008:00007c57 8ed0            mov     ss,ax
0008:00007c59 bc007cfb68      mov     esp,68FB7C00h
0008:00007c5e c0071f          rol     byte ptr [edi],1Fh
0008:00007c61 1e              push    ds
0008:00007c62 686600cb88      push    88CB0066h
0008:00007c67 16              push    ss
0008:00007c68 0e              push    cs
0008:00007c69 006681          add     byte ptr [esi-7Fh],ah
0008:00007c6c 3e0300          add     eax,dword ptr ds:[eax]
0008:00007c6f 4e              dec     esi
0008:00007c70 54              push    esp
0008:00007c71 46              inc     esi
0008:00007c72 53              push    ebx
0008:00007c73 7515            jne     00007c8a
0008:00007c75 b441            mov     ah,41h
0008:00007c77 bbaa55cd13      mov     ebx,13CD55AAh
0008:00007c7c 720c            jb      00007c8a
0008:00007c7e 81fb55aa7506    cmp     ebx,675AA55h
0008:00007c84 f7c101007503    test    ecx,3750001h
0008:00007c8a e9dd001e83      jmp     831e7d6c
```

i dont think debug.com is shipped in windows 10 x64 if you can get yourhands on win732bit etc you can use debug to disassemble the address

```
:>debug
-u f000:fff0 l1
F000:FFF0 EA5BE000F0    JMP     F000:E05B
-u f000:e05b l1
F000:E05B EA3D3A00F0    JMP     F000:3A3D
-u f000:3a3d l1
F000:3A3D FA            CLI
-u f000:3a3d
F000:3A3D FA            CLI
F000:3A3E B800F0        MOV     AX,F000
F000:3A41 8ED0          MOV     SS,AX
F000:3A43 BC493A        MOV     SP,3A49
F000:3A46 E93A8E        JMP     C883
F000:3A49 4B            DEC     BX
F000:3A4A 3ABB1DF1      CMP     BH,[BP+DI+F11D]
F000:3A4E 2E            CS:
F000:3A4F F747020800    TEST    WORD PTR [BX+02],0008
F000:3A54 740E          JZ      3A64
F000:3A56 32C0          XOR     AL,AL
F000:3A58 BC5E3A        MOV     SP,3A5E
F000:3A5B E9E50B        JMP     4643
-
```

I don't think you can step or disassemble the Physical Address f000:ffff in windbg.
I don't think it is mapped at all
I saw  your post !db showing output so I wasn't quiet sure if it is available in x64.
afaik these codes are executed in Real Mode and you cant access them in protected mode with a software debugger like windbg

anyway back to the point
if you want to step through reset vector to MBR use a hardware emulator like bochs.

install bochs (2.6.11 x64 latest at the time of this edit) with the dlx demo

if you installed bochs in windows 10 you may need to give permissions to the bochs folder

(right click bochs folder->properties->security->edit full or write as the case may be)

once permission is granted you can double click the run.bat and you should land on LILo boot prompt

if you are here then close the bochs
open an elevated cmd prompt
and execute ../bochsdbg -f bochsrc

it will stop on Reset Vector

```
C:\Program Files\Bochs-2.6.11\dlxlinux>..\bochsdbg.exe -f ./bochsrc.bxrc
    ========================================================================
                           Bochs x86 Emulator 2.6.11
                  Built from SVN snapshot on January 5, 2020
                    Timestamp: Sun Jan  5 08:36:00 CET 2020
    ========================================================================
    00000000000i[      ] reading configuration from ./bochsrc.bxrc
    00000000000i[      ] installing win32 module as the Bochs GUI
    00000000000i[      ] using log file bochsout.txt
    Next at t=0
    (0) [0x0000fffffff0] f000:fff0 (unk. ctxt): jmpf 0xf000:e05b          ; ea5be000f0
```

set a breakpoint at 0x7c00 using lb 0x7c00 (MBR START)
use s or n to step through
if you single step using s you may need to press `s or ENTER` 42.5 million times to reach MBR

here is a step through from reset vector to MBR using n or next

```
<bochs:5> blist
Num Type           Disp Enb Address
  1 lbreakpoint    keep y   0x0000000000007c00
<bochs:6> u
00000000fffffff0: (                    ): jmpf 0xf000:e05b          ; ea5be000f0
<bochs:7> n
Next at t=1
(0) [0x0000000fe05b] f000:e05b (unk. ctxt): xor ax, ax                ; 31c0
<bochs:8>
Next at t=2
(0) [0x0000000fe05d] f000:e05d (unk. ctxt): out 0x0d, al              ; e60d
<bochs:9>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cut off
Next at t=32
(0) [0x0000000fe0c4] f000:e0c4 (unk. ctxt): rep stosw word ptr es:[di], ax ; f3ab
<bochs:39>
Next at t=160
(0) [0x0000000fe0c6] f000:e0c6 (unk. ctxt): call .+13763 (0x000f168c) ; e8c335
<bochs:40>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cut off
Next at t=5078
(0) [0x0000000fe0cf] f000:e0cf (unk. ctxt): mov word ptr ds:0x0413, ax ; a31304
<bochs:43>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cut off
Next at t=330285
(0) [0x0000000fe1f5] f000:e1f5 (unk. ctxt): call .-18344 (0x000f9a50) ; e858b8
<bochs:146>
Next at t=1403926
(0) [0x0000000fe1f8] f000:e1f8 (unk. ctxt): mov cx, 0xc000            ; b900c0
<bochs:147>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cut off
Next at t=1877324
(0) [0x0000000fe21e] f000:e21e (unk. ctxt): call .+14565 (0x000f1b06) ; e8e538
<bochs:161>
Next at t=5333736
(0) [0x0000000fe221] f000:e221 (unk. ctxt): call .+21186 (0x000f34e6) ; e8c252
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx cut off
(0) [0x0000000fe230] f000:e230 (unk. ctxt): call .+12532 (0x000f1327) ; e8f430
<bochs:167>
Next at t=42311959
(0) [0x0000000fe233] f000:e233 (unk. ctxt): sti                       ; fb
<bochs:168>
Next at t=42311960
(0) [0x0000000fe234] f000:e234 (unk. ctxt): int 0x19                  ; cd19

<bochs:169>
(0) Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000007c00 in ?? () <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Next at t=42409977 <<<<< 42.5 million instructions until MBR is reached
(0) [0x000000007c00] 0000:7c00 (unk. ctxt): cli                       ; fa
<bochs:170> q
(0).[42409977] [0x000000007c00] 0000:7c00 (unk. ctxt): cli                       ; fa

Bochs is exiting. Press ENTER when you're ready to close this window.
```

Comment: I have tried "up FFFF0000 FFF0 l1" in livekd64 but I get the message "Memory access error in 'up FFFF0000 FFF0 l1'".

Comment: I edited the answer I don't think you can disassemble at that address in a software debugger take a look at the edit for a workaround

Comment: Thank you @blabb, I know about software emulators but I really want to see the code of my physical machine. In the mean time I have found a course about the BIOS. It seems there is a register to write to map the BIOS to CPU address space. http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroBIOS.html